# Why does the following expression not simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

During some computation, I sometimes stumble upon expressions such as:

```
expr = 1.4`*^-16 Sqrt[-4.`*^31 x3^2 Cos[0.1` T]^2 Sin[1.` T]^2 + 
9.`*^31 x3 x4 Cos[0.6` T] Sin[0.6` T] Sin[1.6` T]^2]
```

This is something like $10^{-16}\sqrt{10^{32}A}$ and I hoped it would `Simplify` to $\sqrt{A}$.

Why isn't the $10^{-16}$ in front of the `Sqrt` passed into the `Sqrt` so that the powers of 10 disappear?

Additionally, it seems very dangerous since

```
Chop[expr]
```

return `0.`!

Is there a simple way to force MMA simplify the expression?

Comment: It's a matter of accuracy I think. Simplify does work when using exact numbers: `Simplify[(14*^-17) Sqrt[-4*^31 x3^2 Cos[ T/10]^2 Sin[ T]^2 + 
    9*^31 x3 x4 Cos[6 T/10] Sin[6 T/10] Sin[16 T/10]^2]]` .

Comment: "squaring and square rooting" is generally not valid. It assumes that the argument of `Sqrt`  is nonnegative real for all values of its parameters.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes! That's why I want to avoid it!! (cf last sentence in OP). I thought square rooting the square would show that the powers of ten are unnecessary, but apparently it's confusing. I'll remove it in the OP.

Comment: Maybe something like `expr /. a_Real Sqrt[b_] :> Sign[a] Sqrt[Expand[a^2 b]]`

Answer (score 2):

`Sqrt[]` automatically factors out a `Real` factor:

```
Sqrt[1.*^-3 (2. x - 3. y)]
(*  0.0316228 Sqrt[2. x - 3. y]  *)
```

So the following, when executed inside a `Sqrt` will do something like what the OP wants:

```
factorReal = Plus[x_, y__] :>
   With[{coeffs = Replace[{x, y}, Times[k_Real, __] :> k, 1]},
    With[{p = Round[Log2@GeometricMean@Abs@coeffs, 2]},
      2.^p*Distribute[2.^-p*Plus[x, y]]] /; MatchQ[coeffs, {__Real}]
    ];
```

It picks an even power of `2` to factor out, the power that centers the (geometric) mean of coefficients about `1`, provided all coefficients are `Real`.  Remove the condition and replace `Replace[..]` with `Cases[{x, y}, (k_Real | Times[k_Real, __]) :> k, 1]` for a less restrictive rule.

Examples

```
(-4.`*^31 x3^2 Cos[0.1` T]^2 Sin[1.` T]^2 + 
   9.`*^31 x3 x4 Cos[0.6` T] Sin[0.6` T] Sin[1.6` T]^2) /. factorReal
(*
  8.11296*10^31 (-0.493038 x3^2 Cos[0.1 T]^2 Sin[1. T]^2 + 
     1.10934 x3 x4 Cos[0.6 T] Sin[0.6 T] Sin[1.6 T]^2)
*)

expr /. factorReal
(*
  1.26101 Sqrt[-0.493038 x3^2 Cos[0.1 T]^2 Sin[1. T]^2 + 
      1.10934 x3 x4 Cos[0.6 T] Sin[0.6 T] Sin[1.6 T]^2]
*)
```

It can be used in with `Simplify`:

```
Simplify[expr + 2.^6 x + 2^-3 y,
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. factorReal &}
 ]
(*
  64. x + 0.125 y + 1.26101 Sqrt[x3 (-0.493038 x3 Cos[0.1 T]^2 Sin[1. T]^2 + 
       0.554668 x4 Sin[1.2 T] Sin[1.6 T]^2)]
*)
```

`Simplify` returns the "simplest" expression, which might not be the result of applying `factorReal`:

```
% /. factorReal
(*
  4. (16. x + 0.03125 y + 0.315252 Sqrt[
      x3 (-0.493038 x3 Cos[0.1 T]^2 Sin[1. T]^2 + 0.554668 x4 Sin[1.2 T] Sin[1.6 T]^2)])
*)
```