# Coefficients are extremely high

Tags: simplifying-expressions, coefficients

I'm currently doing eigenvalue decomposition of a function.  The answer given by Mathematica contains strange coefficients, on the outside is a factor of 10^-11 and on the inside are several factors of 10^11.

How can I direct Mathematica to reduce these coefficients?

```
a := 32.524
d := 3
siga := 2
lsqr := d/siga
bn[n_] := n*Pi/a
s[x_] := 10 - Abs[x]
psin[n_, x_] :=  Cos[bn[n]*x ]
sn[n_] := 2/a * Integrate[s[x] * psin[n, x], {x, -a/2, a/2}]
an[n_] := sn[n] /(siga * (1 + bn[n]^2/lsqr))
phin[n_, x_] := 
 1/siga*Sum[
   sn[2 k + 1] * psin[2 k + 1, x]/(1 + bn[2 k + 1]^2*lsqr), {k, 0, 
    n}]
FullSimplify[phin[n, x]]
```

---

[image]

Comment: The approaches [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139829/4999) seem to work. (E.g. `sum /. factorReal` or `FullSimplify[phin[n, x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. factorReal &}]`.)

Comment: Not sure why `Simplify` doesn't properly drill down inside the `Sum` but you can fix this if you put `Simplify` inside the `Sum` on your `phin` definition.  You can also do `MapAt[Simplify, expression , {2, 1} ]`

Comment: Best way to avoid this is to use exact values throughout.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thanks!  This seems to have worked. :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, unfortunately, the value 32.524 does not have an exact form representable in Mathematica to my knowledge.  It's an "extrapolation distance" based on neutron transport theory.  And I haven't been able to locate an exact derivation for it.  Just a simplified version based on Fick's Law which gives a slightly different value.  However, when I attempt to put exactly 32 in, the equation churns for several hours without progress.

Comment: I hate when that happens. Oh well, it was worth a try.