# Simplifying powers of 10 in expression with square root

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`FullSimplify` doesn't do anything with the following expression, while it is easy to simplify it by hand.

```
Sqrt[1.4522985860441072`*^-36 + 4.257548915737316`*^-37 x^(2/3)]
 (1.1967621471153255`*^21 x^(1/3) + 7.016839967771709`*^20 x)
```

Is there a way to simplify the powers of 10 inside and outside of square-roots?

Comment: What does the simplification by hand give you?

Comment: I have long calculations after that and they crash the kernel sometimes. Every simplification I make on the expressions help avoiding the crashes. Making them automated would help.

Comment: @L.P. your expression is a function of `x`. May I ask what is the normal order of `x` you use in your work? If it's in single digits, the output is approximately zero.

Comment: x represents the number density of particles in a neutron star in SI units so it's of the order of up to 10^45

Answer (score 2):

From [Why does the following expression not simplify?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139759/why-does-the-following-expression-not-simplify/139829#139829) :

```
factorReal = Plus[x_, y__] :> 
   With[{coeffs = Replace[{x, y}, Times[k_Real, __] :> k, 1]},
    With[{p = Round[Log2@GeometricMean@Abs@coeffs, 2]}, 
      2.^p*Distribute[2.^-p*Plus[x, y]]] /; MatchQ[coeffs, {__Real}]];

Sqrt[1.4522985860441072`*^-36 + 
    4.257548915737316`*^-37  x^(2/3)] (1.1967621471153255`*^21  x^(1/
        3) + 7.016839967771709`*^20  x) /. factorReal

(* 1024.  Sqrt[1.93044 + 0.565925 x^(2/3)]  (1.0137 x^(1/3) + 0.594349 x) *)
```

It seems to factor out powers of 2. I suppose to minimize round-off error.